# XQuery - How to create map using the following data?

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon, xpath-3.0

I have the following data:

```
<courses>
    <course subjectId="3" name="World War II"/>
    <course subjectId="5" name="Algebra I"/>
    <course subjectId="5" name="Statistics"/>
    <course subjectId="15" name="Physics"/>
    <course subjectId="5" name="Algebra II"/>
    <course subjectId="15" name="Chemistry"/>
</courses>
```

I wish to create a xpath script such that it produces the following map:

```
map {
   '3': ('<course subjectId="3" name="World War II"/>'),
   '5': ('<course subjectId="5" name="Algebra I"/>', '<course subjectId="5" name="Algebra II"/>', '<course subjectId="5" name="Statistics"/>'),
   '15': ('<course subjectId="15" name="Physics"/>', '<course subjectId="15" name="Chemistry"/>')
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To use maps you need either XPath 3.1, XQuery 3.1, or XSLT 3.0.

A pure XPath 3.1 solution would be

```
map:merge(
  for $x in distinct-values(course/@subjectId) 
  return map{$x : 
             course[@subjectId = $x] ! 
               serialize(., map{'method':'xml', 'omit-xml-declaration':true()})
             })
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to create a map containing the nodes serialized as XML strings. Putting the node itself in the map value would seem much more useful.

**=== REVISED ANSWER ===**

In your comments you have changed your requirements so that

- You want an XQuery solution rather than XPath
- You want the map to contain the relevant nodes, not an XML serialization of the nodes.

This means you can do:

```
map:merge(
  for $x in course
  group by $id := $x/@subjectId 
  return map{$id : $x})
```

(Not tested: please let us know whether it works! Note that it needs XQuery 3.1)

Comment: Actually I did want to put the node it self (not serialised in a string). Also the query above seems a bit inefficient. For example  if I had 'n'0 courses, it will have to iterate through a maximum of n^2 time if I understand it correctly. I wanted to just iterate it through once.

Comment: Well, efficiency depends entirely on the optimizer. Yes, you are more likely to get decent efficiency if you use an XQuery 3.0 "group by" or XSLT "for-each-group". But you said you wanted a pure XPath solution.

Comment: Apologies I wrote it wrong again. I wanted a XQuery Solution.